# Pycharm. Trouble installing numpy-mlk for Windows

Tags: numpy, installation, pycharm

I'm new to Python and am trying to install numpy-mkl from Pycharm. I get the following error even though I upgraded 'pip' to version 8.1.1 from Pycharm. 
Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipvJw.png

Answer (score 0):

i don't believe numpy-mkl is in the repositories, so it can't be installed the way you're doing it.

if you're running windows, download the appropriate Numpy+MKL .whl file from [Here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). For me, on cpython 3.5 64-bit, the current file is numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

then run:

```
pip install "numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"
```

i'm not sure if the .whl file needs to be in the same folder as your python installation or pip.